# laravel out of box vuejs example not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm simply trying to learn vuejs with laravel and cannot get the example component working.

I have created a fresh route to simply serve the vue example for now.

```
create.blade.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>VUE</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>example</h1>

<div id="app">

<example></example>

</div>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The app.js and example.vue files are exactly as out of the box ( so i won't bother showing example.vue here

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

I have `npm run watch` running and it seems to have built the app files ok.

Controller and route is fine, as page is loading, but I'm getting console error as follows

```
app.js:1697 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'csrfToken' of 
undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1697)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:778)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:41430)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at app.js:66
at app.js:69
```

When i click the console error in chrome it points to the line in app.js:

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = 
window.Laravel.csrfToken;
```

Is it complaining about csrftoken because I've used it as a blade template ?
How can I get it working inside laravel, just so i can play with and learn vuejs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that it is complaining about is in the `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` source, which you'll see is being referenced at the top of the `app.js` file.  In your blade file, before you include your `app.js`, you can set the csrf token value.

```
<script>
    window.Laravel.csrfToken = {{ csrf_token() }};
</script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Or, alternatively, if all you want to do is play with the example as-is, you can probably just remove that line of code from `bootstrap.js`.  But you'll probably need it later once you start using VueJS more.

Comment: hmm thanks but now giving error `create:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: gEUrhuyDkZkWtPxbnFRY2j4ZOdxWfcccN8sGjTk2 is not defined
    at create:18`

Comment: removing that line from bootstrap, however did work ( would like to put it back though for later )

Comment: ok i just needed `{{ csrf_field() }}` without the script tags , thanks marking as correct :)

Comment: oh boy unfortunately bootstrap.js hadn't built itself yet so i thought the above worked when it in fact didn't :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to modify your bootstrap.js file (after axios import line) with the following:

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```